# Should I reserve a taxi in advance to go from Guam airport to hotel?

Tags: luggage, transportation, taxis, guam

I'm going to travel to Guam; there are 4 of us going together.

I never been there, so I'm worried about our baggages sizes fitting in a taxi (approximately  54x66x30 cm, 44x56x20 cm, 44x70x25 cm, and 20x30x20 cm).

Should I reserve a taxi service in advance for us, or can we just pick one of them when we arrive at the airport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the Guam airport, there are authorized airport taxi companies and they are not always available (call taxis can't pick up at the airport). You might want to make advance arrangements through one of the companies found on the [airport list](https://www.guamairport.com/airport-information/passenger-services/taxis).

Most hotels have courtesy vehicles for airport transfers and the hotel hotline telephones are located outside the airport customs exit.